# Find out MySQL database URL from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, remote-server

I have an online MySQL database. I want to figure out the server URL so I can remotely connect to it.

Is there a way I can check my databases URL from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Ask your web hosting company. Remote connections are turned off by default, if I recall correctly.

Comment: be aware that you might not be able to do that at all, if the mysql-server is configured only to accept connections from localhost

Comment: I have already added the remote connection acception but I need the (URL, USER, & PASS) to test it out.

Comment: This is now your fifth question on this same topic within as many hours... is it not possible to modify your previous questions until you get the answer you seek, rather than repeatedly opening new ones?  Furthermore, these sorts of questions might be better suited to another of the SE sites; [sf]? [su]? [webmasters.se]?  I'm not sure.  Probably not SO though!

Comment: What is wrong with having several questions in a topic within an hour? No they are not duplicates of each other, and changing the question after its been answered is extremely unfair to those answering the questions.

Comment: It is just bad form to continuously post multiple questions which are all related to remote access to a server. They may not be duplicates but that seems to be because you are asking a question for each step of the way instead of just asking the question. Your answer however seems to be something that can only be answered by whoever is hosting it. So we can't really help that much.

Answer (score -2):

Remote connections are turned off by default.

Per Ashes999's comment: Ask your web hosting company.

Alternatively, per [Here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=136783.0), try: `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];`.